# Software to check if a function between finite topological spaces is continuous

Tags: general-topology, math-software

What software can be used to check if a given function between finite topological spaces is continuous? Surely someone has already coded software with such capabilities, but it is not easy to find an answer to this directly. An answer to this question could make it easier for someone else to find it by finding the page of this question first.

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom  My question is about finite topological spaces and those can only have finitely many open sets.

Comment: My brain didn't register the "finite" part nvm